# ASP.NET WebForms "Length cannot be less than 0 or exceed input length." on application startup

Tags: asp.net, webforms, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2012

I'm picking up an old ASP.NET WebForms project, and I'm getting this on startup:

> Length cannot be less than 0 or exceed input length. Parameter name:
>   length

What's baffling is, *my application code is nowhere in the stack trace*. Here's what's shown:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than 0 or exceed input length.
Parameter name: length]
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Run(Boolean quick, Int32 prevlen, String input, Int32 beginning, Int32 length, Int32 startat) +6697802
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(String input, Int32 beginning, Int32 length) +48
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.LiteralWithCommentsHelper.FindComments(String source, Int32 sourceStart, Int32 sourceEnd) +89
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.LiteralWithCommentsHelper..ctor(String source, Int32 sourceStart, Int32 sourceEnd) +27
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingParseRecorder.PostProcessBlockList() +311
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingParseRecorder.BuildBlockList(ControlBuilder root) +100
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingParseRecorder.ParseComplete(ControlBuilder root) +101
   System.Web.UI.ParseRecorderList.ParseComplete(ControlBuilder root) +71
   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.HandlePostParse() +184
   System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.HandlePostParse() +13
   System.Web.UI.PageParser.HandlePostParse() +12
   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() +154
   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +110
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +15
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9929933
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +43
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +64
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +191
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +145
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I'm just picking up this project, so I'm not sure what's changed, however I know it worked at some point in the past. :)   Most recently, I upgraded the project file from VS 2010 to VS 2012, however no warnings were thrown and this seems like an odd thing to crop up because of that.   It's a .NET 4.0 project written in VB.NET.

Any ideas on where to look or how to diagnose this further?

Comment: My guess is that there is a mistake an aspx page. Sorry but I can't offer much help, I guess just run the program in debug mode and show us the line it craps out on.

Comment: Running code in debug, I can hit a breakpoint on Application_BeginRequest, but it craps out immediately after that..

Comment: Having the same error after upgrading to Visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok through lots of trial and error, I think I have this figured out.

The culprit is a server-side include in the aspx page:

```
<!-- #include file="include/header.inc" -->
```

When the included file contains a code block, i.e.

```
<% Response.Write("Im broken") %>
```

The above exception occurs.   If the included file only contains plain text/html, it works fine, it's only when a code block is present.

This worked prior to upgrading to Visual Studio 2012, so it seems to be a vs 2012 parser bug...

Answer (score 1):

So, this seems to be a bug in Microsoft Page Inspector. You can tell VS2012 to use Page Inspector instead of Chrome/IE/Firefox when debugging web sites. However, I do not understand why the Page Inspector is involved when I have chosen not to use it, but it is there. To me, it caused both the call stack above and it causes HTML documents to be clipped half way through.

The best solution I have found is to disable the Page Inspector by removing its assembly, in web.config:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess - and it is just a guess - is based on the modules that do appear in your stack trace.

I would guess that either you have something complicated going on in your build, or that you have a malformed tag or compiler directive of some kind on your page.

Check the project file and see if you have any special build scripts, build events, etc.

You might try loading your startup page into the designer and seeing what happens.  Any warnings or info messages?  Any glyphs-of-error?  Redlines?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  No issues in the designer, no warnings on build, and everything looks clean.  Code that hasn't changed for years and was for sure working previously is no longer working..